# s3Slider - Preserving slideshow position and speed bug

Tags: jquery, session, slideshow

I have correctly implemented the s3Slider (http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/) on my site but there are a couple issues I need resolved.

Firstly, there is a jQuery-related issue where the image swap delay incrementally decreases so that after an extended period of time the slideshow speeds up to the point where there is virtually no delay between images. I didn't want to tinker around in the s3Slider.js file because I thought I'd just make it worse.

Second, is there a way, perhaps using PHP sessions, to preserve the position of the slideshow (ie. the current image) between pages so that it doesn't just start over again each time you click a link? I'd like to have about a dozen images, but I feel that only the first few would ever be seen.

I have contacted the author, but he has not replied yet.

**EDIT:** I fixed the speed issue. The author put in an odd condition that basically halves the interval as long as the mouse is outside the slider.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your speed fix Bobe?

Comment: @IanStanway On line 40 should be `var thisTimeOut = (isMouseOut) ? (timeOut/2) : timeOut;` Change to `var thisTimeOut = timeOut;`